# Second-order star convex set: A set whose intersection with any conics passing through two given points consists of at most two connected curves.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, convex-geometry

#### Motivation

> I'm contemplating about what is the geometric property whose special case would be the property of $\mathop{epi}(f)$ for a function $f$ with $f^{(3)}\geq 0$, akin to convexity being the special case of the property of $\mathop{epi}(f)$ for $f$ with $f''\geq 0$? (Note that $S=\mathop{epi}(f)$ of a convex function besides for being convex is such that $S+\{0\}\times \Bbb R_+ = S$, so convexity is indeed a more general property than the one that $\mathop{epi}(f)$ satisfies.)

Consider the following definitions:

> **Definition 1:** We say that a set $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is **second order start-convex** with respect to points $s_0\in S, \bar s_0 \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus S$ if for any conic $C$ containing both $s_0$ and $\bar s_0$ the set $S \cap C$ consists of at most 2 connected sets (in the sense that two branches of hyperbola are regarded as a connected curves).

[image]

In intuitive terms, any conic passing through both $s_0$ and $\bar s_0$ can not "reenter" $S$ twice.

> **Definition 2:** We say that a set $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is **second order start-convex** with respect to line $L\ni (0,0)$ if for any parabola $P$ with the axis of symmetry parallel to $L$ the set $S \cap P$ consists of at most two connected curves.

In intuitive terms, any parabola with the axis of symmetry parallel to $L$ can not "reenter" $S$ twice.

---

#### Questions

1. *Is there an established term for what I call second order start-convex set?*
2. *How to make Definition 2 a special case of Definition 1 for a special choice of points $s_0,\bar s_0$.* (In my understanding all the parabolas with axis of symmetry parallel to a line $L$ have two points at the infinity in common, but I'm struggling formulating it.)

---

#### Analogy

A star-convex set can be similarly characterized as follows:

> A set $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is **start-convex** with respect to the *vantage point* $s_0 \in S$ if for any line $L$ passing through $s_0$ the set $S \cap L$ is connected.

---

#### Closely related questions

- [Geometric characterization of functions with positive third derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617862/geometric-characterization-of-functions-with-positive-third-derivative)
- [A higher-order analogy of the fact that a set is star-convex with vantage point at every point in it iff it is convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618833/1134951)

Comment: Dear @JoséCarlosSantos, I did some corrections, I hope that I did not accidentally undo your edit in the process.

Comment: No, you did not.