# Is there a third-order analogy of quasi-convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization

#### Question

---

I'm contemplating about what should the third-order analogy to strict quasi-convexity be if it should characterize all the functions with the same ordinal properties as functions with strictly positive third order derivative.

> How to characterize all the functions $f\in C^3$, such that $x\mapsto\phi(f(x))$ has strictly positive third-order derivative for some monotonic (increasing) transformation $\phi\in C^3$.

**Notation.** $C^k$ denotes all the functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that are $k$ times continuously differentiable.

---

#### Analogy

---

**Definition.** A function $f\in C^2$ is ***(second-order) strcitly quasi-convex*** iff there exists monotonic transformation $\phi\in C^2$ such that $\phi \circ f$ has strictly positive second-order derivative (i.e. $\phi \circ f$ is strictly convex). This property can be characterized as follows:

> **Characterisation.** A function $f$ is strictly quasi-convex iff for any $x<y<z$,
> $$
>   f(y) < \max\{f(x),f(z)\}.
> $$

---

#### Context

---

**Quasi-convexity:**

Strictly quasi-convex functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ have the same ordinal properties as strictly convex functions do, namely:

- has at most one local minimum,
- every local minimum of $f$ is the global minimum of $f$,
- if $f'(x)=0$ then $x$ is the global,
- has no local / global maximum.

---

**Third-order strict convexity:**

> We call a function $f\in C^3$ is ***third-order strictly convex*** iff $f^{(3)}(x)>0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

**Note.** This concept can be generalized into functions that are not necessarily three times differentiable, I discuss this in [Geometric characterization of functions with positive third derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617862/geometric-characterization-of-functions-with-positive-third-derivative). However, for the sake of simplicity, we can restrict our attention only to functions that are three time differentiable.

Let $f$ be a third-order convex function. Notice that since the second order derivative of $f$ is strictly increasing, it is either entirely convex / concave, or there is a point of inflection $x_*$ at which $f$ changes from being concave to being convex. The following properties follow from there:

- a) $f$ has at most one inflection point $x_*$,
- b) $f$ has at most one local maxim and one local minim,
- c) every local maximum of $f$ is its global maximum on $(-\infty,x_*]$ if $x_*$ exists and otherwise it is global maxim on entire $\Bbb R$,
- d) every local minimum of $f$ is its global minimum on $[x_*,\infty)$ if $x_*$ exists and otherwise it is global minum on entire $\Bbb R$,
- e) if $f'(x_0)=0$, then $x_0$ is a local maximum whenever $x_0<x_*$, and it is a local minimum whenever $x_0>x_*$.

---

**Third-order strict quasi-convexity:**

> **Definition.** We say that function $f\in C^3$ is ***third-order strictly quasi-convex*** iff there exists a strictly increasing function $\phi\in C^3$ such that $\phi\circ f$ has positive third-order derivative.

Apparently, every third-order strictly quasi-convex function has the properties a)-e).

---

> **Question.** Is there an easy way to characterize the third-order strictly quasi-convex functions as it is in the case of the quasi-convex functions?

**Note.** I want a characterization that does not refer to the inflection point $x_*$. Of course, the trivial characterization would be that  $f$ is strictly quasi-concave on $(-\infty,x_*]$ and strictly quasi-convex on $[x_*,\infty)$.