# A higher-order analogy of the fact that a set is star-convex with vantage point at every point in it iff it is convex.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, conic-sections, convex-geometry

There is a simple relation between [star-convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) sets and convex sets:

> A set $S$ is convex iff it is star-convex with vantage point at every point in it.
>
>
> **Proof.**
>
> - $\Longrightarrow \ $  if $S$ is convex, then for every $s_0,s\in S$ the line between $s_0$ and $s$ is in $S$.
> - $\Longleftarrow \ $ if $S$ is star-convex at every $s_0\in S$, then for any $a,b\in S$ the line between $a$ and $b$ is in $S$ because $a$ is a vantage point of $S$.

Thus

> *Convexity* is the property characterizing any set $S$ that is star-convex with vantage point at every point in $S$.

---

When [contemplating about a higher-order analogy to star-convex sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618125/second-order-star-convex-set-a-set-whose-intersection-with-any-conics-passing-t) I came up with the following definition:

> A set $S\subset \Bbb R^2$ is **second-order star-convex** at $s_0\in \mathop{cl}(S)$ and $\bar s_0 \in \mathop{cl}(\Bbb R^2 \setminus S)$ iff $S$ has at most one "hole" along any cubic $C$ passing the points $s_0$ and $\bar s_0$. In other terms, $S \cap C$ consists of at most two connected sets.

**Note:** Closure and connectedness are meant with respect to the homogenous coordinates, so that two branches of a hyperbola form one connected set (as they share a point at infinity), and $s_0$ can be a point at infinity if points of $S$ represented in homogenous coordinates converge to it; and analogically $\bar s_0$ can be a point at infinity if points of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus S$ represented in homogenous coordinates converge to it.

**Example:** Putting $s_0$ and $\bar s_0$ to be both the point $(0,1,0)$ at infinity  (represented in homogenous coordinates), then each conic $C\ni x_0,\bar x_0$ would be a vertically-symmetric parabola (or a line), and the condition would [characterize epigraphs of functions with positive/negative third-order derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617862/geometric-characterization-of-functions-with-positive-third-derivative). (To distinguish between the epigraphs $\mathop{epi}(f)$ of functions with $f^{(3)}\geq 0$ from those with $f^{(3)}\leq 0$ we would need the point $s_0$ to be left from $\bar s_0$, which I don't know how to specify using the homogenous coordinates.)

---

**Question:**

*Can you characterize all the sets $S \subset \mathbb R^2$ such that $S$ is second-order star-convex at all $s_0\in \mathop{cl}(S)$ and $\bar s_0 \in \mathop{cl}(\Bbb R^2\setminus S)$?*

(If it was easier / more interesting to consider $s_0\in S$ and $\bar s_0 \in \Bbb R^2\setminus S$ instead then feel free to do so.)